# SQL Select the minimum across groups, taking the latest value per group (Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table consisting of categories and values (with date and location), I need to generate a running 'worst case value', which is defined as the minimum value across the categories where the value for each category is the latest value as of that date.

Say we have the following table:

| row | location | eventdate | category | value | worstcase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | loc1 | 2023-01-01 | cat1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | loc1 | 2023-01-02 | cat1 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | loc1 | 2023-01-03 | cat2 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | loc1 | 2023-01-04 | cat2 | 6 | 5 |
| 5 | loc1 | 2023-01-06 | cat2 | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | loc1 | 2023-01-07 | cat1 | 5 | 4 |

What I would like to be able to populate is the worst case column values, based on the other columns.

To talk this through per row:

1. There is only one category to look at and one value, so the resulting value is 4
2. There is only one category, with the latest value of 5, so result is 5
3. There are two categories, with the latest values of 5 and 3, so the lowest, 3 is selected
4. There are two categories, with the latest values of 5 and 6, so the lowest, 5 is selected
5. There are two categories, with latest values 5 and 4, so the lowest, 4 is selected
6. There are two categories with latest values 5 and 4, so the lowest, 4 is selected.

So far I have been able to get the absolute lowest value (see DB fiddle link) https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rE5HEmhgsm8eb5j5DsQDY4/0

```
SELECT *, min(value) 
OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY eventdate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS absolute_worst 
FROM sourcetable;
```

But I am not able to take into account only taking the latest value per category as well.

It seems like I kind of need two window functions together, one to get the latest value per category, then another to get the minimum value across the categories, but I cannot figure out how to do this in redshift.

Comment: Can you include a table showing your expected result?